Function from the controller never called in Laravel 11
I have a form to edit my users,
 <form action="{{ route('user.update', ['id' => $user->id]) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
--content--
</form>

A file web.php with all the routes where I have the get method to receive the user's informations
//CRUD Edit Users
Route::get('dashboard/crud/users/{id}/edit/', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::class, 'editUsers'])->middleware(isAdmin::class);
Route::put('dashboard/crud/users/{id}/edit/', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::class, 'editUsersPost'])->middleware(isAdmin::class)->name('user.update');

And a controller with a function to edit my user, I added a 'dd' to see if I'm calling the method but it never does
Public function editUsersPost(ProfileUpdateRequest $request, $id): RedirectResponse
    {
        dd('123');
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->fill($request->validated());

        if ($user->isDirty('email')) {
            $user->email_verified_at = null;
        }

        $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('dashboard.crud.users')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }

This is the profileUpdateRequest Class
class ProfileUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique(User::class)->ignore($this->user()->id)],
        ];
    }

Does it matter that in the file app.php in the cache doesn't contains any middleware ?
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();
I have also updated my route to
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function() {
    Route::put('dashboard/crud/users/{id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::class, 'editUsersPost'])->name('user.update');
});


I get this error now :
Target class [isAdmin] does not exist.

use Illuminate\Http\Request; Public function editUsersPost(Request $request, $id){}

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers need a description to go with the code so other people can understand how this fixes the problem. Without more information it’s not as useful and will probably be down voted.
